# Is it alright to promote a site proposal through the relevant Tag wikis?

Tags: discussion

The [Arduino site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino) would interest a lot of the users of this site, so is it alright to promote it through the [arduino](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino) tag wiki ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Sorry, but tag wikis are not an appropriate place to solicit followers. Advertising a proposal in a tag wiki would not be appropriate.

I know it sounds like a harmless bit of advertising, but there are thousands of proposals who want to be heard. Many have tried posting their announcements to our Q&A sites, adding comments to related questions, posting them throughout the meta site discussions, and even *announcing* them in related proposal subjects. It becomes very noisy fast.

We work hard to keep such solicitations out of our communities, and advertising a proposal in areas where such activities are discouraged will only encourage that same behavior from many many others.

I'm sorry, but advertising is not allowed in tag wikis.